# How to use a ${variable} as part of the hint/default in Netbeans code templates

Tags: php, netbeans, ide, freemarker, template-engine

I have something like the following in a Netbeans code template:

```
/**
 * stuff 
 */
$name = '${name}';
array('${var1 default="persons_${name}"}');
```

How can I make the `default` value for `var1` actually expand the `name` variable as input in the preceding line when using the code template?

I expect to get:

```
/**
 * stuff 
 */
$name = 'joseph';
array('person_joseph');
```

When I fill in joseph for the name variable.

Comment: Is this a question about programming, or NetBeans?

Comment: I guess it is kind of both, but could be viewed as more of a question about Netbeans.  Netbeans is an IDE and the Code Templates are written in FreeMarker template engine syntax so I guess I should add that as a tag maybe.  But your answers are yes and yes.

Comment: Can I remind people that questions about dev tools, configuring and using them are entirely on topic on our site. http://stackoverflow.com/faq - **What kind of questions can I ask here?** - *but if your question generally covers …* software tools commonly used by programmers

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your problem is not with expanding `${name}`, but with specifying a default value. Assuming you want to get `person_joseph` when `var1` is `null` or undefined it should be:

```
array('${var1!"persons_${name}"}');
```

Comment: ddekany, this does not seem to do what I am after.  What the template expands to is, `array('persons_${name}');` rather than persons_joseph.

Comment: That's very strange. FreeMarker does this since version 2.3 (2004-06-15). Maybe NetBeans does some template-preprocessing and escapes the `$`? Anyway, then do this: `array('${var1!("persons_" + name)}');`